# Chart.js 3.7.1 - How can I control the number of ticks on the y axis of a line chart?

Tags: chart.js3

The data will always be integers between -10 and 10, including 0 so there could be a maximum of 21 'intervals' on the y axis.
Regardless of the data, I need the y axis to display from -10 to 10 (including 0) in increments of 1. So I need a total of 21 (ticks?) on the y axis regardless of the data.

I tried this, per the docs:
I also tried it without the steps param:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            max: -10,
            min: 10,                    
            ticks: {
                steps: 21,
                stepSize: 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I got:
[image: Line Chart]

Answer (score 4):

The missing part in your code is `autoSkip: false`.

```
y: {
  max: 10,
  min: -10,
  ticks: {
    stepSize: 1,
    autoSkip: false
  }
}
```

> According to the [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes), `autoskip` is `true` by default.
>
> `autoskip`: If `true`, automatically calculates how many labels can be shown and hides labels accordingly. (...) Turn `autoSkip` off to show all labels no matter what.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('canvas', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [3, 9, 7, 5, 9, 2],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [1, 2, -3, -5, -2, 1],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        max: 10,
        min: -10,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          autoSkip: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```