# Wrap Long Labels in the X-Axis Scales

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a bar chart with very long label names, they display correctly. I decide to cut each word at each space to put them on a new line. Now, the graph displays the labels half the time.

```
const ctx = document.getElementById('mainChart');
_label = [ "JUMBO BAG RED RETROSPOT", "REGENCY CAKESTAND 3 TIER", "PARTY BUNTING", "WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER", "RECIPE BOX PANTRY YELLOW DESIGN", "SET OF 3 CAKE TINS PANTRY DESIGN ", "SMALL POPCORN HOLDER", "NATURAL SLATE HEART CHALKBOARD ", "LUNCH BAG  BLACK SKULL.", "LUNCH BAG SUKI DESIGN " ]
_data = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

function barChart(_data, _label, title, graph) {
    config_bar_chart = {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
            labels: _label.map(x => { return x.split(" "); }), // _labels
            datasets: [{
                label: title,
                data: _data,
            }],
        },
        options: { scales: {y: {beginAtZero: true } }, },
    }
    new Chart(graph, config_bar_chart)
}

barChart(_data = _data, _label = _label, title="", graph=ctx)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the expected outcome ?

Comment: @Sachin Hello, I would like all labels to be displayed

Comment: They are already displayed ? Any particular format you want them

Comment: @Sachin In the second image, not all the labels are displayed

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71527308/2358409

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you are formatting the labels in the chart configuration.

`.map()` function splits the labels by space and return them as an array of strings chart is not able to interpret them correctly as labels.

You need to concatenate split labels into a single string with newline characters `(\n)` between them.

```
labels: _label.map(x => { return x.split(" ").join("\n"); }),
```